# Navigate command not working for VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I attach the following code where I get an "Automation Error" message on the last line copied here (`IE.Navigate`). This code has worked well many many times but now I don't know what's going on. The references are activated, the PC that runs the macro is the same, nothing has changes. I also checked if the link changed but it's still the same.

Basically, what the macro does is open an internet site, it waits for me to login (because I was having issues to login automatically) and then it continues. If I stop the task before it fails, it stays forever in the `DoEvents` loop I have just before the last line. I don't know if this have to do with the other error but that also didn't happen before. Of course, I have to pause the macro, change the execute line to `IE.Navigate` and then I get the message stated above.

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
         (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long
        Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Sub Flujos_Valmer()


Dim URL As String
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ObjCollection As Object, ObjElement As Object, tdCollection As Object, cell As Object
Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection, table As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, t As Integer
Dim TV As String, Emisora As String, serie As String, user As String, pw As String

ultimo = Workbooks("Flujos Valmer.xlsm").Sheets("Macro").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
user = Workbooks("Flujos Valmer.xlsm").Sheets("Macro").Range("P5")
pw = Workbooks("Flujos Valmer.xlsm").Sheets("Macro").Range("P6")

URL = "http://www.valmer.com.mx/"
Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate URL

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
ShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

MsgBox "Por favor inicie sesión en Valmer", vbOKOnly

'HTMLDoc.all.Item("j_username").Value = user
'HTMLDoc.all.Item("j_password").Value = pw
'HTMLDoc.all.Item("btnIngresar").Click

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

ShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
IE.navigate "http://www.valmer.com.mx/es/valmer/corporativo?idProceso=393"
```

Answer (score 0):

Automation errors with IE can have different causes. One of them is to reopen IE after it has just been closed, if it is set to delete cookies etc. on exit. Another is that there are too many "dead" instances in memory. This can be checked and if necessary fixed via the Task Manager.

I think you can login with the following code. (Change your user name and password in the constants.) I think there is no need to open the overlay, because the whole html code will be load.

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
            (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Global Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2

Sub FlujosValmerLogIn()

  Const userName As String = "YourUserName@doit.com"
  Const passWord As String = "YourPassWord"

  Dim url As String
  Dim browser As Object

  url = "http://www.valmer.com.mx/"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  apiShowWindow browser.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  'Set user name
  browser.document.getElementById("emailUsuario").Value = userName
  'Set password
  browser.document.getElementById("contrasenaUsuario").Value = passWord
  'Login
  browser.document.getElementById("btnIngresar").Click
  'Wait for the next page to load (Can be adjusted)
  'Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(hours, minutes, seconds))
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))

  'More of your code here
End Sub
```